# Query on polkadot-apps chain-state cuts of string. Text-overflow?

Tags: polkadot-js, frame, substrate-node-template

Im trying to store a public key in a StorageValue, but when i try to consult it on polkadot-js chain-state, the string gets cut off in the following manner:

> KeyStart...KeyEnd

The value being put in storage has the following declaration:

> let public_key: Vec< u8> = ToRsaPublicKey::to_pkcs1_pem(&pub_key).unwrap().as_bytes().to_vec();

public_key.len() is 97.

I think the string is being cut-off in JS, maybe due to "text-overflow: ellipsis" ?
Is there a way to storage a large string without having to split it?

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive, maybe a github repo link would help a lot? In particular it's difficult to understand what you mean by "I think the string is being cut-off in JS, maybe due to "text-overflow: ellipsis" ?" :)

Comment: This sounds like a polkadot-js display issue. I would raise an issue in that repo with a screenshot showing your truncated key.

Answer (score 6):

It is not actually a display issue as suggested, it is by design where values > 512 bits are truncated. If you wish to have the actual full value, you can always query via the developer tools.

However...

The trimming actually pre-dates the introduction of `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the fields (which are quite a nightmare to get right when things start nesting in weird ways) and as a consequence, actually duplicates effort. So basically it ended in a situation where "pretty formatting" was applied in the middle and then again by the rendering engine. Not quite optimal to say the least.

With that in mind, see [this PR](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/7245) which actually [removes the manual formatting](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/7245/files#diff-1b3384da16415e81132a60c8d8a43593f07d56703551b7e49289d69ff45deb95L60-R60) when converting to a hex display, only relying on the builtin browser version.

You would obviously still see ellipsis at the *end* if it does overflow when something like a hex string is too long, however if you are after the field inspect would work since it is display-only.

For those wanting to scratch an itch: It may actually be quite useful to have a "Copy button" on these output fields, at the very least where `Bytes` or `Hash` or anything that is not structured in a `toHuman()` form is displayed.